# How to automatically fill in proposed code changes in the "Edit" URL for a GitHub file?

Tags: github

EDIT: See comments on Schwern's answer for what I'm looking for in general.  It doesn't have to be exactly what I'm asking for in the question

I have a web app which is an editor.  I would like users to be able to give me a GitHub file URL, my app would automatically load in the file from GitHub, and then I make a process for them which is as easy as possible to submit that change to GitHub again.  Ideally the user wouldn't need to save / upload a file or do any copy/pasting.

GitHub has a URL scheme where you can go to an "Edit" page for a file, make your changes, and then create a PR or create a commit (depending on what you would like to do and your permissions).  This is an example:

https://github.com/rails/rails/edit/main/README.md

Looking at the HTML for the form I see that some of the fields have names associated.  Using those names I can auto-fill the commit title and description:

https://github.com/rails/rails/edit/main/README.md?message=foo&description=bar

But I can't find a way to automatically fill in/replace the actual contents of the file.  Is there a way?

I realize that for some browsers URLs can only be so long (maybe that's not true anymore?), so maybe this isn't perfect.  I'd also be open to other suggestions on how to accomplish what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to do this via web scraping, it's fragile and slow. Use the [Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest).

Specifically, you'd [get access via OAuth](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods), [get the file](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content), let the user edit it, and then [send the edited version](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents).

Comment: To clarify: I'm not trying to do web scraping.  I was just talking about looking at the HTML manually to figure out what parameters could be sent.  But my first thought was to use OAuth and GitHub APIs, but is that possible via a web application?  Do you need private secrets in the client (the browser, in this case)?

Comment: Part of what scared me off that path was this warning not to use `@octokit/auth-app` in browsers: https://github.com/octokit/auth-app.js/#standalone-usage

Comment: @BrianUnderwood Whether you apply the term web scraping the consequences are the same; it's undocumented and not for public use. The form parameters could change tomorrow and your app would break. OAuth is designed for exactly what you're doing; a third party client working on behalf of the user. That particular library may not be relevant.

Comment: Thanks.  I agree that it’s not ideal because the params could change.  Though that library seems to be the official one from GitHub (it’s under the octokit repo).  But I could use some more specifics.

Comment: (Sorry, the octokit organization)

Comment: Specifically, how do I do this in a browser (no backend)?  If I create an app to access the GitHub API the I would need to request access to every public and private repo they have, right?  But even then there would be no flow to go into a PR for a repo they don’t have access to.  I just want an on-ramp to that edit page for a single file.  Doing it via an official API call which redirects to tag page or does something similar would be amazing if you know how

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do exactly what you want.  The ideal tool for this job is an [OAuth App](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/creating-an-oauth-app).  However, creating one with the GitHub API requires that you store a client ID and a client secret, and there is no secure way to store the client secret in a frontend-only app.

Therefore, you'll need to create a backend to create the OAuth app so that you can issue credentials necessary to use the API on behalf of the user or to push data into the repository via the standard protocols.

As Schwern mentioned, you should not try to do this by driving the GitHub web interface.  That isn't a stable interface and may break at any time.

Comment: :-/ Unfortunately a backend isn't an option in this case, bu thanks.  As I said in the comments on Schwern's answer I realize that going through undocumented parameters isn't safe.  Honestly, I could setup some sort of daily script to check if they were still working so at least I would have warning if they change.  But again, it doesn't need to be that page, that page just provides a perfect example of what I'm trying to do.  It would be ideal if GitHub provided an API that I could query which would give me a redirect/temporary URL which achieves this